When are the vertex stars in a triangulated manifold homeomorphic to a ball?
Suppose that $\mathcal K$ is a finite simplicial complex that triangulates a topological manifold $X$ of dimension $n$.
The local star of a vertex $v$ in the triangulation is the unique simplicial complex $\mathcal K_v$ with the following property: an $n$-dimensional simplex $K$ is contained in $\mathcal K_v$ if and only if $v$ is a vertex of $K$.
In other words, $\mathcal K_v$ is the smallest simplicial subcomplex of $X$ that includes the simplices that contain $v$.
I am interested in the topology of that local star.
Q1: Is the local star always an embedded topological ball, and if yes, where can I find a proof of that? Or are there any restrictions on the dimension (e.g., $n \leq 3$?)
Q2: What if the manifold carries the metric induced by the triangulation, and all mappings are required to be locally Lipschitz?
This question is about as elementary as it can get in geometric topology, yet I haven't found an answer in the literature. Some more thoughts about this:

The star of a vertex is homeomorphic to the cone of its link, so it sufficient that the link is an embedded sphere of dimension $n-1$. But this is also necessary because the link is the boundary of the ball.

It seems that the link is at least homotopy equivalent to a sphere of dimension $n-1$ regardless of the dimension $n$. See here.


I am aware of the notion of piecewise linear manifolds but it is difficult to get hold of textbooks. And it seems to be a big gun for something as mundane as this question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem

I presume that any triangulation of the homology sphere must be finite, since otherwise we'd have an infinite triangulation of a sphere, which contradicts the sphere being compact.

@MoisheKohan 1. Is having a piecewise linear atlas equivalent to having a triangulation? I have seen confusion over this. 2. Does there exist a homology sphere (e.g., Poincare) with a finite triangulation? Unfortunately, that's not clear from Wikipedia. I'd be grateful to read some sources.

How much topology do you know? For instance did you ever hear about Poincare homology sphere?
